# How to get properties of a directory using perl script?

Tags: perl

I want to get the details of a directory as like number of files and subdirectories in it and permissions for those.

Yes! it's easy to do it on linux machines using back ticks to execute a command.But is there a way to make the script platform independent.

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use directory handles ([opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) and [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)) to get the contents of directories and [File::stat](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.1/lib/File/stat.pm) to get the permissions

Comment: This is a good solution if (unlike my Path::Class example) you only want to use core modules that are distributed with Perl itself.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Path-Class/lib/Path/Class.pm).  This both gives you an easy interface and also handles all the cross platform things (including the difference between "\" and "/" on your platform) for you.

```
   use Path::Class qw(file dir);

   my $dir = dir("/etc");

   my $dir_count = 0;
   my $file_count = 0;

   while (my $file = $dir->next) {
       # $file is a Path::Class::File or Path::Class::Dir object

       if ($file->is_dir) {
         $dir_count++;
       } else {
         $file_count++;
       }

       my $mode = $file->stat->mode;
       $mode = sprintf '%o', $mode;  # convert to octal "0755" form
       print "Found $file, with mode $mode\n";
   }
   print "Found $dir_count dirs and $file_count files\n";
```

Comment: What if you can't stat the file? Then undef->mode won't work...but you've already counted it in $file_count.

Comment: @oslenshpeegul: What situations exist where would I not be able to stat the file?  I've just successfully read in the contents of the directory...